# Parameterized query not working in connected google sheets

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi please find my query-

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE first_name IN (SELECT TRIM(s) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(@NAME, ',')) s)
```

I am unable to see the results being filtered as per the values I defined in the cell. Is anyone facing a similar issue?